# React Redux Saga boilerplate flow

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have started my react.js project using one of [Starter kit](https://reactjs.org/community/starter-kits.html). I have used one [Boilerplate structure](https://github.com/iroy2000/react-redux-boilerplate). I am trying to learn the actual flow of React
Redux Boilerplate. After gone through their structure I am able to call the API and got data on Component. Here is the flow what I have learned as per the structure:-

a. On componentDidMount I have called a method of Mudules to create an Action.

```
 // On view
 componentDidMount() {
     this.props.getCampaignTopics(1);
 }

 //On Modules
 export const getCampaignTopics = createAction(GET_CAMPAIGN_TOPICS, (id : string) => ({id}));
```

b. On saga when action has been fired, I am calling the API endpoint to get the data

```
// On Saga
export function* getCampaignTopics(actions) {
   let id=0;
   if(actions.payload.id)
   {
       id= actions.payload.id;
   }
   const responsetype = yield call(() => fetch(__CONFIG__.api_url+'topic/' + id,{method:'GET',data:{}}).then(response => response.json()))

  yield put(addcampaignActions.setCampaignTopics(responsetype.data));
  }


function* watchGetHome() {
   yield takeLatest(addcampaignConstants.GET_CAMPAIGN_TOPICS, getCampaignTopics);
}
```

c. After Getting the data I am calling another method of Modules to set data

```
export const setCampaignTopics = createAction(SET_CAMPAIGN_TOPICS, (topics : any) => ({topics}));

export const reducers = {
   [GET_CAMPAIGN_TOPICS]: (state, { payload }) =>
    state.merge({
      ...payload,
    }),
      [SET_CAMPAIGN_TOPICS]: (state, { payload }) =>
        state.merge({
          ...payload,
        }),
    }
```

d. In View I am using selector to separate the indexes

```
// Selector
const addcampaignDataSelector = state => state.addcampaign;

const topicSelector = createSelector(
  addcampaignDataSelector,
  payload => payload.get('topics')
);

export const addcampaignSelector = state => ({
  topics: topicSelector(state)
});
```

e. In component I am getting the value on props

```
// render on Component
const { addcampaign } = this.props;     
topics = addcampaign.topics.toJS().children;
```

So, that's the flow I have got from their tutorial and I am getting the data. But I want to make sure I am on right track or not? Please tell me this is the right process or not?

Next is I want to call a method from component and want receive the response on the component, so I can get the data on a local variable. Could anyone can give me some tutorial or example, So I can go through and learn easily.

Comment: In my opinion flow seems to be fine - only one suggestion I would avoid using `addcampaign.topics.toJS().children` In your component - it is in my opinion a bit clearer if component receives more primitive types rather then immutable.js objects (I assume you are using that lib). So maybe you can expose it also as a selector.

also in `getCampaignTopics` you may put `0` as a default value or`id` parameter so then you don't have to test it in saga.

Comment: So as per my flow I am not using any callback to get the return value, all I am getting on a variable and I have to check that variable has updated or not. Is there any way to ge a callback? Because let's say I have a method getCampaignTopics() using that method I need the Parent and child Topic on the same component then How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> If your looking for a production ready boilerplate,
>   [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) is one of the popular ones.

You seem to be on the right track. This diagram from react boilerplate  [guide](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/docs/general/introduction.md) might help in understanding the flow better. [image]

Comment: Thanks @Anu for your answer. Could you please tell me the process of calling a method to saga and get a callback. I want the return data on a callback method not on a variable.